# Redirect to HTML input value from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, input

So I want to create a simple result page that lets users download their results using the given code.

This is the script:

```html
<form action="" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="logincode">
    <input type="submit" name="send">
</form>

<?php
    $name = $_POST['logincode'];
    $filename = $name.'/'.$name.'pdf';  
    header('Location: ./'$filename'');
?>
```

The principle is when the user writes into the input field, for example (1234) and hits enter, it should redirect him to:

```
./1234/1234.pdf
```

I don't know where the mistake is in my code.

Comment: What goes wrong? From the looks of it, you'll need to put the `header()` command [before any output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php).

Answer (score 2):

Few issues,

- Your header should be before anything else as @showdev mentioned in a comment.
- You're missing a `.` between filename and extension
- You also have a syntax error in the header trailing `''`
- And you should exit redirect headers.

**You should also be checking your variables as you go, plus check the file exists, so you can show errors.**

```
<?php
// check post request
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
   $errors = [];
   // check logincode is set and a number
   if (!isset($_POST['logincode']) || !is_numeric($_POST['logincode'])) {
       $errors['logincode'] = 'Invalid login code';
   } else {
       $name = $_POST['logincode'];

       // check file is found
       if (!file_exists($name.'/'.$name.'.pdf')) {
           $errors['logincode'] = 'Your results are not ready.';
       }

       // now check for empty errors
       if (empty($errors)) {
           exit(header('Location: ./'.$name.'/'.$name.'.pdf'));
       }
   }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <?= (!empty($errors['logincode']) ? $errors['logincode'] : '') ?>
    <input type="text" name="logincode">
    <input type="submit" name="send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a **“.”** before pdf aren’t you?

And also wrong **header('Location: ./'$filename'');**

Try this :)

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['logincode'];

$filename = $name.'/'.$name.'.pdf';
header('Location: ./'.$filename);
?>
```

Comment: thank you brothers but when i tried any of those codes it not redirect to the pdf file the page refresh that's it

Comment: Could it be that you need two dots to get back a folder like “Location: ../‘.$filename); ?

Comment: no sir the folder is in the same script's folder so i sould use one dot 
i think the probem is on the submit button not works good

Answer (score 0):

**It's very insecure code!**

Major changes below:

- **write test for user input data** `TODO by you`
- change order PHP block code first, form (HTML) code next `in snippet`
- add test is post request_method before any $_POST['...']; `in snippet`
- add .(dot) before filename extension i $filename `in snippet`

  ```html
      <?php
      if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
          $name = $_POST['logincode'];
          
          $filename = $name.'/'.$name.'.pdf';  
          header('Location: ./'$filename'');
      }

      ?>

      <form action="" method="post" >
      <input type="text" name="logincode">
      <input type="submit" name="send">
      </form>
  ```

Comment: Whys it insecure?

Comment: It was about @walidz code (without any tests of user input data or http_request method) not yours. Your answer is great. We wrote answers in the same time.

Comment: thank you brothers but when i tried any of those codes it not redirect to the pdf file the page refresh that's it

Comment: It works. I'm sure. I've tested it again a moment ago Server Linux/Apache/php-7.1.13; browsers ffx / chrome / IE11 / MS Edge in all browsers works as expected, it means redirect to pdf file.

Comment: i dunnno why it not work , i'v tried on 000webhost and localhost  and some other servers , always the same thing it not redirec to the pdf file it just refresh when iclick enter

Comment: Check if you have any sign (any space or other in script) before <?php if your server put enything in response - header(...) won't work. (or may be, your saved file with UTF-8 with BOM encoding, change this to UTF-8 without BOM). Snippet of code by @Lawrence Cherone id grat and has error handling, didn you saw any errors from here ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="logincode">
<input type="submit" name="send">
</form>

<?php
if($_POST){
$name = $_POST['logincode'];


$filename = $name.'/'.$name.'.pdf';

header('Location: ./'.$filename.'');
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you brothers 
but when i tried any of those codes
it not redirect to the pdf file  the page refresh that's it

Comment: @walidz I have edited it, will work now, working on my localhost btw.

Comment: when you fill the input with xxxx  and hit enter it will be redirect to xxx/xxx.pdf ? are you sur sir ?

i tried on 3 web hosting but its still not work

Comment: @walidz Yes it's working. Assume that your file url is localhost/location.php, enter xxxx and submit, it will go to localhost/xxxx/xxxx.pdf . If there is no file there, it will display an error. Be sure you have a file at the redirect location.

Comment: its okey sir yes you r right 
the error is the file extention of the script

Comment: its done sir yes you are right 
the error is the file extension of the script
it was html
now its php
all done thank you  sir

Comment: @walidz if my answer helped you kindly upvote it and check the tick next to it.